# List of twitter accounts code works in iOS 6 and not in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, twitter, ios6, ios7

Why below code `works fine in ios6` and `not in ios7` ? am i missing something for ios 7

```
ACAccountStore *account_Store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *account_Type = [account_Store     accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
 arrayOfAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[account_Store accountsWithAccountType:account_Type]];


NSLog(@"arrayOfAccounts %@",arrayOfAccounts); 


if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
{
    ACAccount *acct1;
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]; i++ )
    {
        acct1 = [[ACAccount alloc]init];
        acct1 = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i];
        [array setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",acct1.username] atIndexedSubscript:i];
        // NSString *username = acct1.username;
        // NSLog(@"user at index %d : username %@",i,username);

    }
}
```

This statement `NSLog(@"arrayOfAccounts %@",arrayOfAccounts);` in Debug area gives output:

> arrayOfAccounts ( )

Comment: Is this on simulator or phone? Did you setup Twitter accounts on the iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: yes i have tested on both simulator and on device and also i have setup twitter accounts from settings as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do like this to get array of accounts ,it does give me on both ios 6 and ios 7.
Give a try if its work.Thanks.

Import these framework in your .h file

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

Add this ARC compatible code in your .m file any button action or on which you want accounts array --

```
  /*

// working code for ios 6 and ios 7

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
   // ios 6 working code
}
else 
{
  // ios 7 working code

}

 */

  ACAccountStore *account_Store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *account_Type = [account_Store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];


if (!account_Type)
{

    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Permission not granted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert1.tag = 888;
    [alert1 show];
    return;
}


if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    [arrayOfAccounts removeAllObjects];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    arrayOfAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[account_Store accountsWithAccountType:account_Type]];
    NSLog(@"arrayOfAccounts %@",arrayOfAccounts);

    if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
    {
        ACAccount *acct1;
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]; i++ )
        {
            acct1 = [[ACAccount alloc]init];
            acct1 = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i];
            [array setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",acct1.username] atIndexedSubscript:i];
            // NSString *username = acct1.username;
            // NSLog(@"user at index %d : username %@",i,username);

        }

        //  NSLog(@"array %@",array);

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select your Twitter Account"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

        // ObjC Fast Enumeration
        for (int i = 0 ; i < [array count]; i++)
        {
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [array count];

        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"You have no twitter account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.tag = 999;

        [alert show];

    }



}
else // ios 7 working code
{


[account_Store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:account_Type options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted)
    {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            arrayOfAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[account_Store accountsWithAccountType:account_Type]];
            NSLog(@"arrayOfAccounts %@",arrayOfAccounts);

            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
            {
                ACAccount *acct1;
                array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]; i++ )
                {
                    acct1 = [[ACAccount alloc]init];
                    acct1 = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i];
                    [array setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",acct1.username] atIndexedSubscript:i];
                    // NSString *username = acct1.username;
                    // NSLog(@"user at index %d : username %@",i,username);

                }

                //  NSLog(@"array %@",array);

                UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select your Twitter Account"
                                                                         delegate:self
                                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

                // ObjC Fast Enumeration
                for (int i = 0 ; i < [array count]; i++)
                {
                    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
                }

                [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
                actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [array count];

                [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

            }
            else
            {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"You have no twitter account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                alert.tag = 999;

                [alert show];

            }

            });

            }

}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you need to request access to accounts)

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

}];
```

Comment: Do you have twitter accounts added in settings? Does the app request the access to twitter accounts to user?

Comment: yes i have added twitter accounts in settings - but does not ask permission to user : "AppName" would like Access to twitter accounts

Comment: how to forcibily ask this message

Comment: accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType should ask permission. Check if the app exists in the list under the twitter names in twitter settings and switch is ON for this app

Comment: requestAccessToAccountsWithType call is giving results after sometime - so accounts is displaying no objects at first time and but when user   fires this code second time accounts array is loaded properly and results are displayed

Comment: This result is better than no result. Don't know why this happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43975/discussion-between-bhavya-kothari-and-nerowolfe)